# How Can I Create the Login Activity In Android

Tags: android, if-statement

I am trying to display an error message when the username and password do not match in my application. On button click with the proper name and password it is working perfectly and display the message login successful but else condition is not working. Where am I wrong?

**Login.java**

```
private class SigIn extends AsyncTask<String, String, String[]> {
          private final Context _context;  

          public SigIn(Context context){
                _context = context;

            }
        ProgressDialog pDialog = new ProgressDialog(LoginActivity.this);
        @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
        @SuppressLint("WorldReadableFiles")
        @Override
        protected String[] doInBackground(final String... params) 
        {
            ConnectivityManager conMgr = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
            if (conMgr.getActiveNetworkInfo() != null
                    && conMgr.getActiveNetworkInfo().isAvailable()
                    && conMgr.getActiveNetworkInfo().isConnected()) 
            {
                HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                try 
                {
                    pDialog.setMessage("Please wait signing in...");
                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() 
                    {
                        public void run() 
                        {
                            pDialog.show();
                        }
                    });

                    JSONObject job= new JSONObject();
                    euid = uedit.getText().toString();
                    epass = pedit.getText().toString();

                    euid.replace("" ,"%20");
                    epass.replace("" ,"%20");
                    job.put("status_key","2");
                    job.put("method", "login");
                    job.put("email", euid);
                    job.put("password",epass );



                /*
                    System.out.print("latitude is "+latitude);
                    job.put("latitude",latitude);
                    job.put("longitude",longitude);*/

                    StringEntity se = new StringEntity(job.toString());

                    HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://suntechwebsolutions.com/clients/mobileapp_now/webservice.php");

                    httppost.setEntity(se);

                    HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
                      String data = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());
                      System.out.println("response "+data);

                      JSONObject jo = new JSONObject(data);

                    Log.d("response", jo.toString(4));

                    JSONArray jArray = jo.getJSONArray("driver_details");  
                    Log.d("Array", jArray.toString(4));
                    JSONObject adv= jo.getJSONObject("advertisement_count");  
                    advertisement_count=adv.getString("count(*)");
                    System.out.print("advertisemnet"+advertisement_count);              
                    for (int i=0; i < jArray.length(); i++)
                    {
                        try {
                        JSONObject jsob = jArray.getJSONObject(i);

                                mfname = jsob.getString("first_name");
                                msname = jsob.getString("Surname");
                                mun = jsob.getString("unit_no");
                                mstreet = jsob.getString("street_name");
                                msuburb = jsob.getString("Suburb");
                                mstate = jsob.getString("State");
                                mpassword = jsob.getString("password");
                                mpostcode = jsob.getString("post_code");
                                mlicense = jsob.getString("driving_lic");
                                mid = jsob.getString("authority_id");
                                mmobile = jsob.getString("mobile_no");
                                memail = jsob.getString("Email");
                                login_token=jsob.getString("login_token");
                                mimagelicense=jsob.getString("license_pic");
                                mauthcard=jsob.getString("audit_card_pic");
                                mpic=jsob.getString("face_pic");
 } catch (JSONException e) {
                             e.printStackTrace();
                        } 
}
pref=getSharedPreferences("Driver", MODE_WORLD_READABLE);
                    SharedPreferences.Editor edit=pref.edit();

                    edit.putString("mfname", mfname);
                    edit.putString("msname", msname);
                    edit.putString("mun", mun);
                    edit.putString("mstreet", mstreet);
                    edit.putString("msuburb", msuburb);
                    edit.putString("mpassword", mpassword);
                    edit.putString("mpostcode", mpostcode);
                    edit.putString("mlicense", mlicense);
                    edit.putString("mid", mid);
                    edit.putString("mmobile", mmobile);
                    edit.putString("memail", memail);
                    edit.putString("login_token", login_token);
                    edit.putString("mimagelicense", mimagelicense);
                    edit.putString("mauthcard", mauthcard);
                    edit.putString("mpic", mpic);
                    edit.putString("advertisement_count", advertisement_count);
                    edit.commit();

    if(jo.getString("err-code").equals("0"))
                        {
                            final AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(LoginActivity.this);
                            alert.setTitle("Login !!!");
                            //alert.setTitle("Login unsuccessfull !");
                        alert.setMessage(jo.getString("message"));
                            //alert.setMessage("Username and password does not match.");
                            alert.setPositiveButton("Ok",
                                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                        int whichButton) 
                                {
                                    pDialog.dismiss();
                                    dialog.dismiss();

                                    /*Intent tabint = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),agreement.class);
                                           startActivity(tabint);*/
                                    Intent tabint = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),agreement.class);
                                       startActivity(tabint);
                            }
                            });
                            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                                public void run() {
                                    alert.show();
                                }
                            });
                        }

                        else if(jo.getString("err-code").equals("300"))
                        {
                            final AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(LoginActivity.this);
                            alert.setTitle("Login!!!");
                            alert.setMessage(jo.getString("message"));
                            alert.setPositiveButton("Ok",
                                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                        int whichButton) 
                                {
                                    pDialog.dismiss();
                                    dialog.dismiss();

                                    //Intent tabint = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),agreement.class);
                                         //  startActivity(tabint);
                            }
                            });
                            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                                public void run() {
                                    alert.show();
                                }
                            });
                        }
                        else
                        {

                            final AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(LoginActivity.this);
                            alert.setTitle("Alert !");
                            alert.setMessage(jo.getString("message"));
                            alert.setPositiveButton("Ok",

                                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                        int whichButton) {
                                    dialog.dismiss();

                                }
                            });
                            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() 
                            {
                                public void run() 
                                {
                                    pDialog.dismiss();

                                    alert.show();
                                }
                            });
                        }


                    }
                    catch (Exception e) 
                    {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
                return params;
            }
```

After login with different username and password it will give me error in log cat like:

```
6-10 03:41:20.550: W/System.err(32253): org.json.JSONException: No value for driver_details
06-10 03:41:20.560: W/System.err(32253):    at org.json.JSONObject.get(JSONObject.java:355)
06-10 03:41:20.560: W/System.err(32253):    at org.json.JSONObject.getJSONArray(JSONObject.java:549)
06-10 03:41:20.560: W/System.err(32253):    at com.sunmobileappnow.mobileappnow.LoginActivity$SigIn.doInBackground(LoginActivity.java:263)
06-10 03:41:20.560: W/System.err(32253):    at com.sunmobileappnow.mobileappnow.LoginActivity$SigIn.doInBackground(LoginActivity.java:1)
06-10 03:41:20.560: W/System.err(32253):    at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288)
06-10 03:41:20.560: W/System.err(32253):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
06-10 03:41:20.560: W/System.err(32253):    at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
06-10 03:41:20.570: W/System.err(32253):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
06-10 03:41:20.570: W/System.err(32253):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
```

Comment: what you get in driver_details?

Comment: post your json when login is unsuccessful

Comment: JSONArray jArray = jo.getJSONArray("driver_details"); No value is coming from this

Comment: Tell how can I resolve this.

Comment: Check response properly and debug your code and you will get the cause of issue.

Answer (score 0):

You ommit one } in your class.

Please you add } then run .

I expected you solve your problem.

Comment: If that was the problem, there would be a compile-time error and not runtime exception.

Answer (score 0):

You try to get

`JSONArray jArray = jo.getJSONArray("driver_details");`  but When you try to login via wrong user name and pasword then the json do not return `driver_details` values.

That reason it show this error.

```
org.json.JSONException: No value for driver_details
```

Comment: if user name and password wrong then your webservice return any message that user name and password wrong . check this message then read details of the json.

Comment: But sir I have already mentions that I want message that password or username is not correct from webservices when the wrong credential are entered.

Comment: First check it jo.getString("err-code").equals("0") then call this JSONArray jArray = jo.getJSONArray("driver_details");